# Integration.js not working in publisher actions (Winter '15 issue?)

Tags: publisher-action

I'm trying to use some [console integration](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_console/) features inside a publisher action. In particular, I'm using [addEventListener](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_console/Content/sforce_api_console_addeventlistener.htm). I'm trying to listen to a custom event (CallRefreshEvent) that is being raised by a different part of the application.

For simplicity's sake, I've created a very simple page to test this:

```
<apex:page >
<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/32.0/integration.js" />
<apex:includeScript value="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js" />
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            function handleMessage(msg){
                console.log ('Event received');
                var focusedPrimaryTabId = msg.message;
                sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(function(result){
                    var enclosingPrimaryTabId = result.id;                   
                    if(focusedPrimaryTabId === enclosingPrimaryTabId){                       
                        console.log ('Tab focused');
                    }
                });                
            };
            sforce.console.addEventListener('CallRefreshEvent', handleMessage);
       });
</script>   
Testing integration.js
</apex:page>
```

If I load this page inside the Salesforce Console (ie: as a tab), it works perfectly.
If I create a publisher action to display this page then I get the following error as soon as it's loaded:

ServiceDesk.js:281 addEventListener: Unsupported Operation: This API cannnot be used on this component.

This was working perfectly for us a few months ago, and it stopped working recently. However, we haven't made any code changes. We suspect that this stopped working with the Winter 15 release.

Can anyone verify this? Or provide a workaround/fix?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you still facing this issue ? I am stuck with same issue and just wanted to check if you got the solution. Thanks!

Comment: The issue still persists, so we had to move to a different API. We're currently using the sfdc.canvas.publisher API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried below thing instead of eventListner and it worked fine for my use case. See if it would help you.

This code snippet passes the Hello world event to the action my_custom_action.

Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({name:"publisher.customActionMessage",
payload:{actionName:"my_custom_action", message:"Hello world"}});

This code snippet is what my_custom_action uses to listen to the Hello world event.

Sfdc.canvas.publisher.subscribe([{name : "publisher.customActionMessage", onData :
function(e) {alert(e.message);}}]);

Comment: We checked the release notes for Winter 15 (https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_winter15_release_notes.pdf) and came across the canvas publisher API. We finally rewrote our code using this, so I will approve this answer. Thanks!

Comment: The documentation for the publisher.js API is here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/case_feed_dev/Content/case_feed_dev_guide_component_interactions.htm

Answer (score 0):

The error means the tab id specified is not found. Looks like the publisher created iFrame/page doesn't have a name.

The workaround (disclaimer: not tested): 
You should have control over this iFrame/page, so you can simply do window.name = "myUniqueName_ideally_iframeDomId" BEFORE calling the console api.